# Replacing a pattern within a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am cleaning some text removing stopwords and extra punctuation. I found a patterns repeated through most of the texts which is --- (three dashes) at the end.

For example

```
Text
it is a wonderful day ---
What's up?---
Hi guys, everything is going ok.
What do --- you think? --
```

Expected output would be

```
Text
it is a wonderful day
What's up?
Hi guys, everything is going ok.
What do --- you think? --
```

I should replace the --- at the end of the rows with an empty space and count how many cases there are within the column.
I think that I should consider to use endswith() (`df['Text'].str.endswith('---')`) and then replace it with empty space.
If I wanted to count how many rows/sentences ends with ---, how could I do that?

Comment: so you only want to replace the `---` at the end?

Comment: yes, if it could be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly a simple regex and `.value_counts` should do the trick.

> If I wanted to count how many rows/sentences ends with ---, how could I do that?

```
df['Text'].str.contains('---$').value_counts()

True     2
False    2
Name: Text, dtype: int64
```

> I should replace the --- at the end of the rows with an empty space

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('---$','')

                               Text
0            it is a wonderful day 
1                        What's up?
2  Hi guys, everything is going ok.
3         What do --- you think? --
```

regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/c4XCg9/1)

> --- matches the characters --- literally (case sensitive)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: Thanks, Manakin. Only one thing: instead of count how many in total there are, I was looking at something on assigning a 1/0 value where there was that pattern. Is it something easy to do?

Comment: yep `df['count'] = df['Text'].str.contains('---$').astype(int)` :) @Val

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it would give you some idea to proceed further.

```
string = """
It is a wonderful day ---
What's up?---
Hi guys, everything is going ok.
What do --- you think? --"""

puntuations = ['-']
rsult = []
for x in string.split(' '):
    for pun in puntuations:
        if pun in x:
            x = x.replace(pun, '')
            rsult.append(x)
        else:
            rsult.append(x)

print(' '.join(rsult))
```

Comment: Hi Prakash, unfortunately the proposed code does not answer my question. I should not replace all the - but --- and only if they are at the end of the row. For example, in the last sentence, I should still have --- and -- as at the end I have only -- (and not ---), and the three - within the sentence should be kept as they are not at the end. I would be able to replace all the - symbols in the column, but not only those ones satisfying a specific pattern. Thank you for your help